# Using password_hash() to protect password on login?

Tags: php

Being new to programming and php but eager to learn I quickly figured out that there are so called "best" and "bad" practices. Bad practice is the use of MD5 encryption for example which I was about to learn and implement. However, I just recently learned about the relatively new password_hash() function that automates a lot (yes, I did'nt use the word alot :D) of the process of encryption such as adding salt. Correct me if im wrong though.

So here I am with a question about how to correctly use this function.

```
function login_check() {

    $connection = database();

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password_hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $query = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE name = ? AND password = ?";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $name, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
    $counter = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);

    if($counter > 0 && password_verify($name, $password_hash)){
        $_SESSION['login'] = $name;
        header('location:../../index.php');
        exit;
    }
    else {
        header('location:../../failed.php');
        exit;
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    login_check();
}
```

So this is how far I go and to be honest Im not sure if this is even the right way. Could need your feedback. Is this ok or are there any additional things to consider to make this work?

I read that there is no need to create own salt and other hash related things anymore.

Comment: This is testing a password, but how did you store that password originally? Did you use `password_hash()` on the password you stored on the database? Sorry if this sounds like a silly question but it has to be asked!

Comment: @RiggsFolly No I didnt. Do I have to do this when the user registers? Right now my password is stored as a normal one. I set up a test user with "123" as the password.

Comment: you do `password_hash()` on entered password , and then `password_verify()` it with hash from database!

Comment: Yes of course. Otherwise your hashed password wont match the one you stored on the database

Comment: @MozzieMD is the verification process ok though? So I just need to ensure the hash is also stored in the database right?

Comment: Storing a hashed password is one of the major reasons for hashing. It protects the users password from internal ( admin ) hacking

Comment: @RiggsFolly is this good enough or do we still need to create our own encryption system with custom salt etc?

Comment: @MozzieMD Actually that should be `password_verify($plainTextPassword, $hashFromDb)`

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah you are right!

Comment: From the manual :- _Warning
The salt option has been deprecated as of PHP 7.0.0. It is now preferred to simply use the salt that is generated by default._ So i would not use a manual salt

Comment: Anyway, first things first: First change the Registration process to `password_hash()` the users password and then store the hashed password on the database. Then come back here and change the code to test the users entered password using `password_verify($plainTextPassword, $hashFromDb)`

Comment: An upvote for the _yes, I did'nt use the word alot :D_ alone! :D

Comment: @AcharyaAnurag thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `$password` in your `password_verify()` function instead of `$name`.

So change

```
password_verify($name, $password_hash)
```

To

```
password_verify($password , $password_hash)
```

**Note:**-`password_verify()` Need your password and password that store in your database. Not your hashed password.

Also you need to store hashed password in your database.

And compare your password with hashed

```
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $name, $password_hash);
```

Comment: Oh ya, misstyped there. I need to ensure I have the hashed version on the database though right? Right now I have 123 as the password

Comment: yes you need to store hashed password instead of 123. Then after your `password_verify()` function works

Comment: so right now im using 1) Prepared statements, 2) password_hash(), 3) I store my database credentials outside the root in a ini file. Am I missing anything?

Comment: and store hashed password in your database and match with hashed

Comment: This won't work, because $password_hash will be different each time you generate it, and no results will be fetched from DB.

Comment: `password_verify()`
Need you password and pass that store in your database. Not your hashed password.

Answer (score 2):

Upon registration, `password_hash` the entered password and store the hashed password in your database.

Upon login:

1. Fetch the hashed password from the database by the username, e.g.:

   ```
   SELECT password FROM users WHERE name = ?
   ```
2. Verify the hashed password with the just entered password:

   ```
   if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $databaseResult['password'])) {
       // match
   }
   ```

You do ***not***:

- `password_hash` anything upon login
- `SELECT ... WHERE password = ?` upon login, because you need the stored hash's random salt in order to produce the same hash again, so you cannot search for anything by hash in the database

Answer (score 0):

General idea is to query your database by username (email), and retrieve user details with hashed password. Then, you run `password_verify()` with entered password and OLD hash from database. If it matches, it will return true.

I did not test code, but it should give you example how to use those functions correctly.

```
<?php
function login_check()
{
    $connection = database();

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $query = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE name = ?";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $name);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
    $counter = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
    $user = mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt); // retrieve old user password

    if ($counter > 0 && password_verify($name, $user['password'])) {
        $_SESSION['login'] = $name;
        header('location:../../index.php');
        exit;
    } else {
        header('location:../../failed.php');
        exit;
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    login_check();
}
```